# Data Catalog: error updating Tag - Error 400: Unsupported field mask path: "column", supported field masks are: fields

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-data-catalog

I am attaching a tag-template to a column of a BigQuery table. For this, I am using Terraform and I have just recreated the code in the terraform documentation.

```
resource "google_data_catalog_entry" "entry" {
  entry_group = google_data_catalog_entry_group.entry_group.id
  entry_id = "my_entry"

  user_specified_type = "my_custom_type"
  user_specified_system = "SomethingExternal"

  schema = <<EOF
{
  "columns": [...]
}
EOF
}

resource "google_data_catalog_entry_group" "entry_group" {
  entry_group_id = "my_entry_group"
}

resource "google_data_catalog_tag_template" "tag_template" {
  tag_template_id = "my_template"
  region = "us-central1"
  display_name = "Demo Tag Template"

  fields {
    field_id = "source"
    display_name = "Source of data asset"
    type {
      primitive_type = "STRING"
    }
    is_required = true
  }
  force_delete = "true"
}

resource "google_data_catalog_tag" "basic_tag" {
  parent   = google_data_catalog_entry.entry.id
  template = google_data_catalog_tag_template.tag_template.id

  fields {
    field_name   = "source"
    string_value = "my-string"
  }
  column = "address"
}
```

Docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/data_catalog_tag

Unfortunately, every time I run 'terraform apply' twice, I obtain the next API error:

```
Error: Error updating Tag "projects/xxxx/locations/europe-west2/entryGroups/xxxx/entries/xxxx/tags/xxx": googleapi: Error 400: Unsupported field mask path: "column", supported field masks are:
fields
```

It is like Terraform is not happy when I create this resource twice.
To avoid this I have used:

```
  count    = local.created_tag ? 1 : 0
```

But I wonder what might be the cause and if there is a better way to solve the issue.

Comment: The error is returned by the Data Catalog API and it’s because the [PATCH method](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.entryGroups.tags/patch#query-parameters) of an entryGroup tag only allows updating the `fields` field. Terraform seems to update the tag instead of deleting and creating a new one. So from Data Catalog side, I would suggest you to open a Feature Request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655468&template=0) asking the team to allow updating additional fields such as column or whatever fields you need.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tlaquetzal, very useful. I will request it

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any updates on the issue ?

Comment: It is still pending. The Data Catalog team has received the request and will be analysing it. I will update the post if any solution come across.
IssueTracker Number: 180021381